# CustomViewService (Login) passing additional values to CustomUserService - IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3

I want to use IdentityServer3 in my solution, but one of my requirements is to connect to multiple databases for users, clients and scopes.

So, I want to customize the Login page and add a database selector. I’m doing this with a custom view service.

Then, when the user click on login button, my custom user service is called, but I don’t know how to send the database selector value to my AuthenticateLocal implementation on custom user service.

I need to know the database selector value in custom client and scope services as well.

I saw this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/2032044.aspx?Custom+User+Service+for+Thinktecture+Identity+Server+V3 where Brock said it isn’t possible.

Does the latest version of IdentityServer3 have any way to archive what I need?

Thanks!

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom form elements to the submit on the login page. In your custom `IUserService` add the `OwinEnvironmentService` as a ctor dependency to get access to the incoming OWIN environment. You can then wrap that with an `OwinContext` for convenience. Then in your `AuthenticateLocal` you can read the posted custom form elements to do whatever you need in your logic.